# PHP Curl Script Working in browser, but doesn't trigger in a function

Tags: php, api, http, curl

Absolutely baffled by this problem. I have a curl script, when pasted in a separate file, put the url of the file in a browser and hit enter, it works. But when the same script is to be triggered under a function. It doesn't run.

The script sends card details for payment processing e.g. It sends details to mastercard which deducts pay and returns a response to be acted upon

Here is the script (NOTE I have changed some details for privacy):

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://cardsapi.example.com/step1.php?cvv=467&cardno=123456789011&ccexpmonth=02&ccexpyear=18&amount=15000&email=example@example.com&names=TestUser&transaction_id=111111111&callback=http://cardsapi.example.com",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Authorization: Bearer UVZoQk9rcFhDcWxlR1RPSnJBa1RaRkZQSjdZdlVSRzdZTThHVldLUU1jZz06MTIzNDU6UTIydkozVll4RzFMWUV2MkViSDl5UVN3NFFRanZrNVJoVThQM0pXTXRIRT06MTk3LjI0OC4xNDkuNjI6MDQvMDAvMTcgMTIwMA==",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Postman-Token: 98defbc9-f5af-3b48-b416-b9d31325df07",
            "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
          ),
    )
);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

If I put this code in something like curlscript.php and run it ex. http://localhost/scripts/curlscript.php , it works. But when I put the code under a function e.g. send_process_pay() in a file e.g. process_pay.php it doesn't trigger. process_pay.php validates the data, triggers function if ok and acts upon response from MasterCard/VISA etc.

How can I make it run under a function?

EDIT:

This is how it is housed in a function and called:

```
function send_process_pay(){
      $curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://cardsapi.example.com/step1.php?cvv=467&cardno=123456789011&ccexpmonth=02&ccexpyear=18&amount=15000&email=example@example.com&names=TestUser&transaction_id=111111111&callback=http://cardsapi.example.com",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Bearer UVZoQk9rcFhDcWxlR1RPSnJBa1RaRkZQSjdZdlVSRzdZTThHVldLUU1jZz06MTIzNDU6UTIydkozVll4RzFMWUV2MkViSDl5UVN3NFFRanZrNVJoVThQM0pXTXRIRT06MTk3LjI0OC4xNDkuNjI6MDQvMDAvMTcgMTIwMA==",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Postman-Token: 98defbc9-f5af-3b48-b416-b9d31325df07",
        "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
      ),
)
);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; 
} else {
return $response;
}       
}
```

and then:

```
if(data_valid){
  $the_response = send_process_pay();
}
```

So when the data is valid, the response is stored in a variable.So other proccesses are activated depending on response

Update:

Having had a look at the code, the cURL script is indeed working. The difference between running the file over putting it as a function is that, when running a file, the response, which is html with a javascript auto-submit executes but in the function, the reponse (html) is returned but not executed.

The problem now is to figure out how to run the response so that the auto-submit javascript function in it works.

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question, but when you put this code inside a function are you calling it afterwards?

Comment: @WilliamJanoti no. I typed that for here. Let me edit it to another name if it helps

Comment: If you removed some code for privacy, was any of the removed code containing $variables not existing in the function's scope?

Comment: Please provide your attempt code in `process_pay.php` that pertains to calling the `send_process_pay()` function and handling the `$response` (which is currently being echo'd? not returned?).

Comment: @IncredibleHat. No. Actually the values have been hardcoded for the test. I haven't yet substituted the hardcoded values with variables so they (values) are not the problem

Comment: @IncredibleHat The code above is the one under send_process_pay(). For the purposes of stackoverflow I changed the api url, card_num ber, email etc. So exactly the same code in both scenarios only that one is housed under a function. the $response part doesn't really matter at this point, so long as those values hit the server, MasterCard/Visa processes and you in fact get an email from them on whether it was successful or not

Comment: Thats not what I was asking. You say you are having trouble when you wrap that curl code in a function `function send_process_pay() { ... curl code ...}` ... but you didn't show how you are calling that function or handling the response from it.

Comment: @IncredibleHat added code of how it's housed in a function. Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: Yes thats better... and that doesn't work? Then I don't know what to suggest from this point, because there is nothing that stops curl functions from working within another defined function and/or method. I would look to your 'data_valid' conditional and figure out why its not even calling your function in the first place.

Comment: @IncredibleHat unfortunately no. that's what I don't understand. I have done a json_log and it is returning a response but, the data is not hitting mastercard/visa servers. when run outside a function i.e. as a separate file via browser, data hits the servers and an appropriate email is sent